# $NC$ and $FNC$ oracles low for functional and Stockemeyer classes respectively?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, parallel-computing, oracle-machines, oracles

We know $P^{NC}=P$ and $FP^{FNC}=FP$ hold. Do $FP^{NC}=FP$ and $P^{FNC}=P$ hold?